# How can I efficiently count the number of occurrences of a given character within certain range of a string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, algorithm

Given a unsorted string, e.g. "googol". I want to find the number of occurrences of character "o" in the range: [1, 3). So, in this case, the answer would be 1.

However, my method has complexity O(N^2). The problem of my method is that copy array needs O(N) time. Therefore, I was looking for another way which would be more efficient. Space complexity does not matter to me. Because I am learning string processing algorithms, it is better if I could achieve this algorithm on my own.

Any help would be appreciated.

My method.

```
tmp = [0] * 26  # 26 alphabet
occurrences_table = []
tmp[ord(a_string[0])] += 1
occurrences_table.append(tmp)
for i in range(1, len(a_string)):
    temp = occurrences_table[i - 1]
    temp[ord(a_string[i])] += 1
    occurrences_table.append(temp)
```

Comment: Check [collections.counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) to work on a particular range of your string.

Comment: @umutto. But it's like I am learning some string processing algorithm. So I would like to implement this algorithm on my own.

Comment: @kevinnnluo - you really should mention this restraint in your original question.

Comment: @Christian König. Yes, my bad. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to use [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and want to implement it yourself, your code can be tidied up and sped up a little by using dictionaries.

```
a_string = "googol"
my_counter = {}
for c in a_string[:2]:
    my_counter[c] = my_counter.get(c, 0) + 1
```

which would give you:

```
{'o': 1, 'g': 1}
```

To explain it a little further `a_string[:2]` gets the characters up to index 2 in your string (`'google'[:2]` = `'go'`) and `for c in a_string[:2]:` loops over those 2 characters.

In the next line, `my_counter.get(c, 0) + 1` tries to get the dictionary value for the key 'c' (a single character in your string), if it exists it returns its value, if not returns 0 and either way adds the incremented value back to the dictionary.

---

**EDIT:**

Complexity should be just O(n) due to the for loop since the complexity of `dictionary.get()` is constant.

I've measured it up and for very small strings like yours, this method was 8-10 times faster than [Collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), but for very large strings it is 2-3 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
a_string = "googol"
occurrences = Counter(a_string[0:2])
```

which results in

```
Counter({'o': 1, 'g': 1})
```

Notice that array slicing works on strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use standard libraries:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(islice('googol', 1, 3))
Counter({'o': 2})
>>> Counter(islice('googol', 0, 2))
Counter({'g': 1, 'o': 1})
```

(`islice` avoids a temporary list.)

If you want to do it manually:

```
>>> s = 'googol'
>>> counter = dict()
>>> for i in range(0, 2):
...     if s[i] not in counter:
...         counter[s[i]] = 1
...     else:
...         counter[s[i]] += 1
... 
>>> counter
{'g': 1, 'o': 1}
```

The point is: use a `dict`.

Comment: I think his `range [1, 3)`-notation starts counting characters from position 1 up until and excluding position 3 - so effectively [0:2] in python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Becasue the range is [1, 3), the substring is "go", which only has one "o". But it's like I am learning string processing algorithm, so I would like to achieve it on my own.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that when I saw you answer ;)

Comment: @kevinnnluo Indices in python start from 0, that's why I was confused.